# Minify JSON with PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, minify

Is there a way to minify (remove all whitespace in this case) a JSON file to turn this

```
[
    0.000005,
    0,
    0
],
[
    219.740502,
    0.003449,
    4.177065
],
[
    45.210918,
    0.003365,
    -16.008996
],
[
    344.552785,
    0.030213,
    277.614965
],
```

to this using PowerShell

```
[0.000005,0,0],[219.740502,0.003449,4.177065],[45.210918,0.003365,-16.008996],[344.552785,0.030213,277.614965],
```

I have tried several online "minifiers" however the file contains over 100,000 arrays and basically broke all the online minifiers.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just for your information when you manipulate PowerShell object and convert them to JSON (`ConvertTo-Json`) you've got the `-compress` param :

```
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{Name="Hugot";GivenName="Victor"} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

gives :

```
{"GivenName":"Victor","Name":"Hugot"}
```

Comment: much better answer

Answer (score 18):

Adding to JP's answer,

```
(ConvertFrom-Json $json) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

This is useful if you already have json.  If you don't do the `ConvertFrom-Json` on the front, then it will encode the line breaks with `\r\n` and the quotes with `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so with a basic regex. If you have this in a file try the following. You must include the -Raw parameter or the file will be passed one line at a time which will prevent the regex from removing the newline character.

```
(Get-Content C:\Some\File.json -Raw) -replace '\s','' | out-file C:\some\outfile.json
```

Comment: Big warning here! This command will output the result in UTF-16. That's not really a problem unless you are trying to compute a hash on the content. Just make sure that the resulting encoding is what you expect. Even when using the -encoding switch, the output will give you UTF8 with BOM. That will mess with your hash computation of the file.

Comment: Won't this remove spaces from strings, which proper minification shouldn't do?